# CSRF token for remote validation does not work on regenration token

Tags: csrf-protection

CSRF token for remote validation does not work on regenration token , 
whne i try to click on submit button three ajax request goes and on which 2nd one is canceled automatically , and on  validate function of jquery submitHandler event is not triggered

here is the code

```
},
            'email':{
               required: true,
               email:true,
               remote:{
                    url: base_url+'user/check_email',
                    type:"POST",
                    data:{
                        email:function() { return $('#email').val(); },
                        id:function() { return $('#userid').val(); },
                        csrf_test_name:function() {return readCookie('csrf_cookie_name'); },
                    }
                },
            },
            'cpassword':{
                equalTo: "#password"
            },



function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}



*/
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();

/*
```